# Redux Persist TypeError: store.dispatch is not a function

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-hooks, store, redux-toolkit

While following a tutorial, I got this store.dispatch is not a function error. I've searched stackoverflow for a while, but cannot seem to locate any errors. What am I missing?

Image showing the error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AekWH.png

```
import {configureStore, combineReducers} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import cartReducer from './cartRedux'
import userReducer from './userRedux'
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({user: userReducer, cart: cartReducer})
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export const store = () => configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})


export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

index

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {store, persistor} from './redux/store'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you declared your `store` to be a function that returns a configured store.

```
export const store = () => configureStore({ // <-- a function
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})
```

and you pass a reference to this `store` function `persistStore`

```
export const persistor = persistStore(store) // <-- store not invoked
```

While you *could* just invoke the `store` function each place this would be bad since you'd effectively create multiple store instances in different parts of your app that won't work together. You should just export and consume an already configured store object.

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```