# TypeError: store.dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm following along the [Redux Writing Test guide](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests) to test my Redux/TypeScript application. I ran into `TypeError: store.dispatch is not a function` error.

I followed this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164034/redux-persist-typeerror-store-dispatch-is-not-a-function) of exporting and consuming an already configured store object but I still receive the error. What am I missing?

(my attempt)

```
export default function setupStore(preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
    return configureStore({
        reducer: persistedReducer,
        middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
            getDefaultMiddleware({
                serializableCheck: {
                    ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
                },
            }),
        preloadedState,
    });
};
```

Here are the files with the related code.

test-utils.tsx

```
import setupStore from '../store';

interface ExtendedRenderOptions extends Omit<RenderOptions, 'queries'> {
    preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>;
    store?: AppStore;
}

export function renderWithProviders(
    ui: React.ReactElement,
    {
        preloadedState = {},
        store = setupStore(preloadedState),
        ...renderOptions
    }: ExtendedRenderOptions = {},
) {
    function Wrapper({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): JSX.Element {
        return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
    }

    return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) };
}
```

store.ts

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    version: 1,
    storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: userReducer, cart: cartReducer });
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
export default function setupStore(preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
    return configureStore({
        reducer: persistedReducer,
        middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
            getDefaultMiddleware({
                serializableCheck: {
                    ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
                },
            }),
        preloadedState,
    });
};

export let persistor = persistStore(setupStore as any);
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch'];
```

Navbar.tsx

```
const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
    const cartQuantity = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.cart.cartQuantity);
    const { currentUser } = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);

    return (
        <Language>EN</Language>
    );
};
```

Navbar.test.tsx

```
it('renders same span text in Navbar component', async () => {
    renderWithProviders(<Navbar />);
    const spanElement = screen.getByText(/EN/i);
    expect(spanElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've basically about the same issue as the post you linked to with the `setupStore` function and needing to call it to get an actual `store` object.

`AppDispatch` needs to be the `typeof store.dispatch`. Try the following where  `AppDispatch` is "picked" from the `AppStore` type.

store.ts

```js
export default function setupStore(preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: {
          ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
        },
      }),
    preloadedState,
  });
};

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
export type AppDispatch = Pick<AppStore, "dispatch">;
```

index.tsx - Import `setupStore` and `persistStore` here and instantiate the `store` `persistor` objects.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import persistStore from "redux-persist/es/persistStore";
import setupStore from "./store";

const store = setupStore();
const persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[image: Edit typeerror-store-dispatch-is-not-a-function]

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I attempted `export type AppDispatch = typeof setupStore.dispatch` and `export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;` but still receive the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @ln09nv2 I see. I tried the above in a project I'm in the middle of converting over to using RTK and these type exports had the same signature as my regular `export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;` export, so it looked to be equivalent. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I was not able to import my whole project into a CodeSandbox as I reached the max limit of 500 modules. I manually copy/pasted the relevant files instead to reproduce the issue. [Here you go](https://codesandbox.io/s/typeerror-store-dispatch-is-not-a-function-3s9ebn)

Comment: @ln09nv2 The code in your sandbox (*and likely the real code it is based on*) was failing to compile because you were not passing an actual `store` object to the `persistStore` function. Move creating the `persistor` into `index.ts` where you should instantiate a `store` object to be passed to the Redux `Provider` component and `persistor` to `PersistGate`. I've updated my answer and included a working fork of your sandbox.

Comment: It worked! I was confused about passing the actual store object when following the guide. Thanks!